# Pgbouncer timeouts

Tags: postgresql, timeout, pgbouncer

I try to use pgBouncer to eliminate short network disconnects. I did a test, where I had Clinet->pgBouncer->Postgresql. When connection is made from Client, I disconnect network cable, if I connect it back faster than in ~15 sec it still works. If not, I am totally disconnected, and pgBouncer logs:

> db/user@server.address.com:5432 closing because: server conn crashed?
> db/user@127.0.0.1:49837 closing because: server conn crashed?
> db/user@127.0.0.1:49837 Pooler Error: server conn crashed?

How I can control that timeout?

PS: In my `pglib` on client side, in connection string timeout is set to 60 sec.

Lukas

Comment: When I made test network cable was disconnected between pgBouncer and Postgresql (client to pgbouncer was connected without any interruptions).

Answer (score 5):

I would try to adjust option `server_connect_timeout`. According to doc - If connection and login won’t finish in this amount of time, the connection will be closed. Default is 15 sec.

Anyway, good source for pgbouncer tuning is https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html.